Extending the “point at infinity” valuation for function fields
I understand that if $A$ is a Dedekind domain and $K=Frac(A), L/K$ finite separable, and $B$ is integral closure in $A$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime then there is a bijection between places extending $v_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and primes of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$
Let $A = \mathbb{F}_q[t], K = \mathbb{F}_q(t)$ and $L/K$ be a finite separable extension, and $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. If $\pi$ is an irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$, then this allows us to easily extend $v_{\pi}$ to a prime of $B$ lying over $(\pi)$. There is also a valuation $f\mapsto p^{\deg f}$ and I want to know how this extends.
If there is one valuation we can use the product rule for global fields. But if there are many I'm not sure what to do. My feeling is that there should be only one valuation, since infinite places are rare.

Function fields (restricting myself to finitely generated extensions of transecndence degree one over a finite field) behave a bit differently from number fields in the sense that the infinite place/valuation /point at infinity is no different from the rest of them (all non-archimedean for one).
Undoubtedly you have seen that Möbius transformations
$$
t\mapsto \frac{at+b}{ct+d},
$$
$a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{F}_q, ad-bc\neq0$, extend to automorphisms of the function field $\Bbb{F}_q(t)$. Furthermore, they permute the points on the projective line $\Bbb{F}_q\cup\{\infty\}$ (or even  $\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}\cup\{\infty\}$), underlying the same fact.
In that same spirit you can think of $K=\Bbb{F}_q(t)$ also as $K=\Bbb{F}_q(u)$, $u=1/t$, and, a fortiori, as the field of fractions of $\tilde{A}:=\Bbb{F}_q[u]$.
Then the point at infinity corresponds to $u=0$, or to the valuation coming from the irreducible polynomial $\pi=u$. It then follows that the valuation at the point $t=\infty, u=0$:

ramifies in the extension $L=K(\sqrt u)$ (assume $2\nmid q$ for otherwise the extension is inseparable),
splits in the extension $L=K(v)$, $v(v-1)=u$, and
is inert in the extension $L=K(v)$, $v^2+1=u$, when $\Bbb{F}_q$ has no solutions of $x^2+1=0$ (i.e. $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$).

Geometrically this means that you should move to a different affine chart of the projective plane. See for example introductory books on algebraic geometry for the required machinery.

Will delete, when a suitable duplicate target is found. I have been criticized by some users for posting answers in comments, and try and meet them halfway by posting comments as answers.

"Function fields behave a bit differently from number fields in the sense that the infinite place/valuation /point at infinity is no different from the rest of them." Does this require the function field to have positive characteristic, i.e. the place at infinity is nonarch?
